# How can I clear an image with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, image, rest, django-rest-framework

I thought my problem was https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/937 which should have been fixed by https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/1003 but it appears, whether I send in None or empty string, DRF isn't happy.

I'm using Django 1.11.6 and DRF 3.7.7

```
class Part(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class PartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ('id', 'image')

class PartDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Part.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PartSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

# put image, works fine
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg') as fp:
    image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 200))
    image.save(fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    data = {'image': fp}
    self.client.put('/path/to/endpoint', data, format='multipart')

# clear image, attempt #1
data = {'image': None}
self.client.put('/path/to/endpoint', data, format='multipart')
AssertionError: {'image': ['The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.']}

# clear image, attempt #2
data = {'image': ''}
self.client.put('/path/to/endpoint', data, format='multipart')
AssertionError: <ImageFieldFile: None> is not None
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: I found your solution [here](https://groups.google.com/g/django-rest-framework/c/5Y9KmjyicIo) in google groups of deleting the image in perform_update before calling serializer.save().

Is this still working for you? I would like to PATCH or PUT a FileField with an empty value to clear it, but I was not able to get your solution to work.

Answer (score 8):

You have to specify the image field explicitly to allow it to be null.

use this:

```
class PartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ('id', 'image')
```

check [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield) for more details.

Comment: I tried this, and sending both `None` (attempt #1) and `''` (attempt #2) yield the same result.

Comment: Best answer for shortest and effective.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into something like this trying to write an Angular app that contacts a Django system through Django REST framework.  DRF automatically generates forms for updating objects. If there's a `FileField` on an object and you don't upload a file into the update form when you submit it, the framework can automatically remove a previously uploaded file and leave the object with no file at all.  The object's field is then null.  I wanted my app to have this capability, that is, objects can have an attached file, but it isn't required, and a file can be attached and later removed.  I tried to accomplish the removal by constructing a `FormData` object and sending it as a PUT request, but I couldn't figure out exactly what value to specify for the file field to make DRF delete the previously uploaded file, like what happens in DRF's automatically generated forms.

These didn't work:

```js
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.set('my_file', null); // TypeScript wouldn't let me do this
    fd.set('my_file', ''); // Same error as your attempt #2
    fd.set('my_file', new Blob([]); // Error about an empty file
```

What finally worked was

```js
    fd.set('my_file', new File([], ''));
```

which apparently means an empty file with no name.  With that, I could send a PUT request that deletes the file attached to the object and leaves the resulting `FileField` null:

```js
    this.http.put<MyRecord>(url, fd);
```

where `this.http` is a an Angular `HttpClient`.  I'm not sure how to construct such a PUT request in Python.

To leave the file in place, don't set anything for `'my_file'` on the `FormData`.

On the Django side, I was using a subclass of `ModelSerializer` as the serializer, and the underlying FileField in the Model had options blank=True, null=True.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the docs for `FileField.delete`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete

I would create an `update` method on your serializer that would clear the image using the ORM call

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
     instance.part.delete(save = True)
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that I reimplement your code.

```
Django version:2.0
DRF version:3.7.7 as you say in the question.
```

Firstly, the conclusion is that the method in your attempt #2 is right in my tests. However, attempt #1 has no effect and my error is the same as yours. However, the images saved before is not deleted in the filesystem.  The followings are my TestCase. Make sure that you use the client provided by the DRF rather than the django itself.

```
from PIL import Image
from django.test import Client
import io
import os
import unittest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
class PutTests(unittest.TestCase):
def generate_photo_file(self):
    file = io.BytesIO()
    image = Image.new('RGBA', size=(100, 100), color=(155, 0, 0))
    image.save(file, 'png')
    file.name = 'test222.png'
    file.seek(0)
    return file


def test_imagetest(self):
    """
    test put Image object
    :return:
    """
    self.client = Client()
    print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( os.path.dirname(__file__) ), '2018s.jpg'))
    f = self.generate_photo_file()
    data={
        'image': f,
    }
    # if you want to insert image in the testCase please let class PartDetail inherits from ListCreateAPIView.
    self.client.post('/puttestimage/', data=data, format='multipart')

def test_image2test(self):
    # this won't work in my test.
    self.client = APIClient()
    data = {'image': None}
    self.client.put('/puttestimage/1/', data=data, format='multipart')
#
def test_image3test(self):
    # this will work in my test.
    self.client = APIClient()
    data = {'image': ''}
    self.client.put('/puttestimage/2/', data=data, format='multipart')
```

The basic idea is that I first insert one image into the database, they I clear this image by your attempt#1 and #2.

```
class PartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
class Meta:
    model = Part
    fields = ('id', 'image')

class PartDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Part.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PartSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'puttestimage/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/',     PartDetail.as_view(),name='imageput'),
    url(r'puttestimage/', PartDetail.as_view(), name='imageputs'),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Django 1.11.6 (and DRF 3.7.7)